# Overriding serialEvent twice

Tags: java, serial-port, overriding, arduino

I wrote a class called `ArduinoSerial` that implements `SerialPortEventListener`.

I use this class as a library that I import into another program called `ArduinoGUI`, that creates a swing GUI with a series of checkboxes in it.

When I want to write to the serial port I have a private member variable of the `ArduinoGUI` class private `ArduinoSerial` arduino;

I call the `arduino.output.write(byte b);` function and it works fine.

The issue is that the internal `ArduinoSerial` class overrides the read function and currently spits the output out to system.out.

```
    @Override
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            String inputLine=input.readLine();
            System.out.println(inputLine);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
                            System.out.println("But nothing much to worry about.");
        }
    }
    // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
}
```

This is not what I want however, I'd like to read the serial data into a byte array within the `ArduinoGUI` class but I'm not sure how to override this method a second time and/or write an event listener for data on the serial port while getting the `ArduinoSerial` class not to read and discard the buffer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can't override method twice but you can do followed thing:

```
public class ArduinoGUI extends JFrame implements ArduinoSerialItf { 

private ArduinoSerialItf arduinoSerialItf = null; 
private ArduinoSerial arduinoSerial = null;

 //init 
 public ArduinoGUI(){
    arduinoSerialItf = this;

   arduinoSerial = new ArduinoSerial(arduinoSerialItf );

 } 

@Override
public void onEventReceived(SerialPortEvent oEvent){
   // in GUI class you get event from ArduinoSerial 
}

}
```

Create interface:

```
public interface ArduinoSerialItf {
 public void onEventReceived(SerialPortEvent oEvent);
}
```

ArduinoSerial class:

```
public class ArduinoSerial implements SerialPortEventListener {

private ArduinoSerialItf arduinoSerialItf = null;

public ArduinoSerial(ArduinoSerialItf arduinoSerialItf){
  this.arduinoSerialItf = arduinoSerialItf;
} 

@Override
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    // when we call this method, event goes to GUI class
    arduinoSerialItf.onEventReceived(oEvent);

}
```

Comment: A problem is : public class ArduinoGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame already, is it possible for it to extend ArduinoSerial too ?

Comment: You can't extend 2 classes, only 1 available.

Comment: How do I get around this problem, I have created ArduinoSerial as an abstract class that implements SerialPortEventListener, however not the serialEvent method. My child class already extends jFrame, which it needs to do to create the GUI, how do I get it to also extend ArduinoSerial so it can implement the missing SerialPortEventListener?

Comment: Also, if I implement SerialPortEventListener in the ArduinoGUI instead, I can't create an instance of the abstract superclass, so how do I call its methods ?

Comment: Well, its design problem. Its not good practice to implement Swing and other API into the same class. Build 1 class for GUI only and initiate there other class (MySuperClass) mentioned above. By using `Interface` you can be able to pass data from `MySuperClass` to GUI class

Comment: I changed my code, see above. GUI class will get event from ArduinoSerial class that got event from `serialEvent`. Enjoy

Comment: Thx, do I create a new class called ArduinoSerialItf ?

Comment: its not class but interface. Separate java file

Comment: Thanks, it now works.... man that was a lot of work but I couldn't have done it without you! I have learned quite a lot in the process and still trying to figure out the minutiae.